# Different foreign key and ManyToOne in Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I am just a beginner of using doctrine.

I have a 2 tables, Book and chapters

```
BOOK[ BID, NAME ]
CHAPTER[ CID, BID, ChapName ]
```

Chapter Class:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $cid;
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="Chapters")
 * @var Book
 */
private $Book;
```

Book Class:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $bid;
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Chapter", mappedBy="Book", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true))
 * @var Chapter[]
 */
private $Chapters;
```

I am not sure if it's correct, but when I try to query on Chapters to get the chapter id 1. This is the error:

```
Unknown column 't0.Book_id' in 'field list''
```

But if I try to call "$book->getChapters()->first()->getChapName()". I get the ff. error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php

Line Number: 1193
```

What could be the problem because I am very confuse.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the @JoinColumn on $Book.
This is needed because you don't use the default column names.

Code:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="Chapters")
 * @JoinColumn(name="BID", referencedColumnName="cid")
 * @var Book
 */
private $Book;
```

Here's the whole documentation on mappings with doctrine:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html